# Find value from JSON and assign it to the Object [Node.js]

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object

```
var obj = {
    name: "apple",
    color: "red",
    size: 12
}
```

This is my object, I want to find and take apple's price value from JSON and assign it to this object.

```
var prices = {"banana":12,"orange":8,"apple":22}
```

Now I need to take apple's price and assign it to the object. How do I do that?

Comment: `apple.price = prices.apple`??

Comment: i want to say `prices` isn't really JSON (at least not in the string-representation way i see people talk about most of the time). even though `prices` has double-quotes around its properties it's still an object literal and you can freely assign to and from it like any other javascript object.

Comment: Ok, but how do I choose a variable of object: obj.price = prices.(apple.name)

Comment: are you asking how to get the name of the property instead of the value?

Comment: i need to choose json value by giving it object value. `prices.apple.name` it makes a triple object/json?

Comment: `prices.apple` is all you need. it's not JSON. it's an actual object, so you can use dot-notation to access that object property. if the object property name is a variable, you can use bracket-notation instead `prices[someVar]`

Comment: obj.price = prices[obj.name]

Answer (score 0):

```
var prices = {"banana":12,"orange":8,"apple":22}

var obj = {
    name: "apple",
    color: "red",
    size: 12
}

obj.price = prices[obj.name]
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
var obj =
{
name:"apple",
color: "red",
size: 12
}
var prices = 
{
"banana":12,
"orange":8,
"apple":22
}
obj.price=prices[obj.name];
console.log(obj.price);
```

Comment: Can you mention the reason for downvoting. If there is something wrong with code, mention and downvote so that we can learn something from that. Don't just downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but the answer is not formatted correctly and it's kind of confusing because you don't need NodeJS to test JavaScript code - you can do that with whatever tool you'd like.  Also your answer does not address OP's actual object he's supposed to be working with.